# Create api-gateway lambda integration using aws-cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cli, aws-api-gateway

I need to create an api gateway using aws client. I successfully create and integrate with my aws-lambda function using web console. But I am confused with aws-client. These are the steps I followed.

1. Create api gateway and integrate with my sample lambda function using web console.

[image]

2. Deploy created api and export as json file.
3. Create new api gateway using exported json file using aws-cli. Command like this.

   ```
   aws apigateway import-rest-api --body file://tmpfile.json --region us-east-1;
   ```

But it created only resources & methods.

4. For integrate api method with my lambda function, I execute command like this

   ```
   aws apigateway put-integration --rest-api-id 42ku123id8u3a --resource-id core-api-dev --http-method DELETE --type AWS --integration-http-method POST --uri 'arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:my-lambda-function-arn' --region us-east-1
   ```

   But it produces error message like this

> An error occurred (NotFoundException) when calling the PutIntegration operation: Invalid Resource identifier specified

Is it possible to integrate api gateway method with existing lambda function using aws client? What is Resource identifier?

Comment: The docs have an example lambda integration: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/put-integration.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can run `aws apigateway get-resources` to get the `resource-id`

```
aws apigateway get-resources --rest-api-id 42ku123id8u3a --region us-east-1
```

It will return a JSon like

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "path": "/resource/xxx",
            "resourceMethods": {
                "POST": {}
            },
            "id": "_yourresourceid_",
            "pathPart": "xxx",
            "parentId": "ai5b02"
        }
    ]
}
```

you can take the *id* from this JSon and use it on your command for `aws apigateway put-integration`

Comment: So I did exactally that, but still get the error: An error occurred (NotFoundException) when calling the PutIntegration operation: Invalid Method identifier specified

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you should export as JSON in step 2 'with integration extensions'. In the console there are 3 options for export type, and the middle one will include the integrations and authorizers in the export. Then when you import you'll have the integrations already.