# Integrate Lambda with rest endpoint using aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-cli

i am trying to integrate lambda and rest api gateway endpoint using aws cli and running the following command but getting follwing error

```
aws apigateway put-integration  --region us-west-2 --rest-api-id 91b73m5i10  --resource-id pjg2ac --http-method GET --type AWS --integration-http-method GET --uri arn:aws:apigateway:us-west-2:lambda:path/apigateway/functions/arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:xxxxx:function:sendFile_Trips_divyanayan/invocations
```

An error occurred (NotFoundException) when calling the PutIntegration operation: Invalid Method identifier specified

Saw this related article but was not of much help

[Create api-gateway lambda integration using aws-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39788094/create-api-gateway-lambda-integration-using-aws-cli)

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-custom-integrations.html  ..another link for reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is self explanatory. It likely that your `ApiGateway` endpoint doesn't have GET method on that resource.

Please add the same and then try to run the above command.

You might need to add the --credentials parameter which is `ARN` for `IAM` role which allows this integration with `lambda` function.

You also need to change `--integration-http-method` to `POST` (This is the default integration method between apigateway- lambda.

```
aws apigateway put-integration  --region us-west-2 --rest-api-id 91b73m5i10  --resource-id pjg2ac --http-method GET --type AWS_PROXY --integration-http-method POST --uri arn:aws:apigateway:us-west-2:lambda:path//2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:xxxxxxxx:function:sendFile_Trips_divyanayan/invocations --credentials arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxx:role/lambda-role
```

Also the role that is given in the credentials should have below thins in trusted relationships (Principal)

```
    {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
            "Service": [
                "apigateway.amazonaws.com",
                "logs.amazonaws.com",
                "lambda.amazonaws.com"
            ]
        },
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Note**: *Dont expose the accountId while asking questions on external forums.*

Comment: When i tried to test api from web console .Execution failed due to configuration error: API Gateway does not have permission to assume the provided role arn:aws:iam::3xxxxxx:role/lambda_role.Is this some access issue realted to my account .if i removed role on  put_integration i get follwing error :Execution failed due to configuration error: Invalid permissions on Lambda function

Comment: In the IAM role you need to add the service name (i.e. apiGateway) who can assume the role.

Comment: is passing credentials mandatory ? i have one lambda role which we have for doing poc with some minumum permissions so when i use that role it gives me error as API Gateway does not have permission to assume the provided role arn:aws:iam::3xxxxxx:role/lambda_role

Comment: this is my command again .aws apigateway put-integration  --region us-west-2 --rest-api-id 0bovdlngz6  --resource-id fuoq79 --http-method GET --type AWS --integration-http-method GET --uri arn:aws:apigateway:us-west-2:lambda:path/greeting/functions/arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:xxxx:function:helloworld-divyanayan_lambda/invocations .where /greeting is the resource and api gateway name is HelloWorld-divyanayan

Comment: Go into the lambda_role and in Trust relationship tab add apigateway.amazonaws.com as trusted entities.

Comment: So do you have lambda_role in your account..? specify the role that you have on lambda function..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187121/discussion-between-sangam-belose-and-divyanayan-awasthi).

Comment: what are other types available here --type AWS.if i go and see web console  of end point ,i dont see lambda function  on right hand side where we have method executions